# how can i extract a 6 digit alphanumeric part of txt from a string (i want them kept together not pulled apart)

Tags: powerquery

How can I extract a 6 digit alphanumeric part of txt from a string (I want them kept together not pulled apart).

ie I want to extract 3B3520 from 'Media Hold Vessel 3B3520, Vessel drawing'

Can extract the text or numbers alone but not both.

Comment: What have you tried? You just need a bit of logic, and `std::isalpha` and `std::isdigit` will help.

Comment: That's not 6 digit string; it is a six character alphanumeric string with some digits in it.  So please:  How many **digits** must the string contain?  Are there other strings that include digits that might confound a search method? Is this string separated from the rest of the text by any kind of delimiter (eg a space)?  If not, how can you tell where the 6 characters start/end?

Answer (score 1):

To extract a six character alphanumeric string where at least 2 of the characters are digits, you can add a custom column with the formula:

```
=List.Select(
    Text.Split(
        Text.Remove([Column1],{",",".","!","?"}),
    " "), 
    each (Text.Length(_)=6) and 
        (Text.Length(Text.Remove(_,{"0".."9"})) <=4)){0}
```

Adjust the number of needed digits by adjusting the `Text.Length(...)<=4)` parameter.

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each 
    List.Select(
        Text.Split(
            Text.Remove([Column1],{",",".","!","?"}),
        " "), 
        each (Text.Length(_)=6) and 
            (Text.Length(Text.Remove(_,{"0".."9"})) <=4)){0}, type text)
        
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

First 6 characters in the 4th word

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Custom", each Text.Start(Text.Split([Column1]," "){3},6))
```

6 characters starting in position #19

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Custom", each Text.Middle([Column1],18,6))
```

6 characters preceding the comma, version 1

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Custom", each Text.Middle([Column1],Text.PositionOf([Column1],",")-6,6))
```

6 characters preceding the comma, version 2

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Custom", each Text.End(Text.Split([Column1],","){0},6))
```

Regex looking for a number followed by a letter followed by 4 numbers

```
let fx=(text,regex)=> Web.Page("<script>var x='"&text&"';var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');var b=x.match(y);document.write(b);</script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}                       
in let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source , "Custom", each fx([Column1], "[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]{3,}"))                      
in  #"Added Custom"
```

First 6 characters after the word "Vessel "

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Custom", each Text.Start(Text.Split([Column1],"Vessel "){1},6))
```